# Linux shared object: Is it possible to avoid name mangling when exporting c++ function with std::vector argument?

Tags: c++, shared-objects, name-mangling

I am trying to create a shared object in Linux that will export a function with std::vector argument. The function is name-mangled in the shared object. Is it possible to avoid it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Name mangling is how the linker handles things like function overloading.  What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It might be possible, but might not be as useful as you think. The application using the library must still be built with basically the same compiler and standard library as the shared object, or the vector won't be the same and you'll have undefined behavior.

Comment: You could export function not taking `std::vector` and simply pass the data in a form that's C compatible, e.g. `extern "C" { void PrintVectorImpl(int const* data, size_t length); } template<class Alloc> void PrintVector(std::vector<int, Alloc> const& vec) { PrintVectorImpl(vec.data(), vec.size()); }` but if you need vector resizing, the signature of the dll function would need to be a bit more complex, e.g.: `void FillIntVector(void* vectorPtr, int* (*resizeVectorAndGetFirstElement)(void*, size_t));`

Comment: You can pass you vector as a void pointer to the vector. That way you get a C compatible function, but you loss type safety completly, but that will always be the case if you do not want to have mangled names, because that is what it is for.

Comment: @StephenNewell when I provide a shared object with documentation to someone else, it is nicer to tell him to search a certain function name without a mangling.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mentioned the constraint to build the shared object and the application using it with same compiler and same standard library version. Is it a general issue with standard library arguments in exported functions ? Is it considered a bad practice to use arguments from the standard library ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you not providing headers with the so?